# Strange leaves marks on zinnia and Mint

Tags: diseases, leaves, mint, zinnia

This morning I have noticed some strange marks on my Zinnia leaves and the leaves of the mint growing nearby:
[image: Zinnia leaves]
[image]

What could that be? And what could be done with it? They both grow on an east-oriented balcony with a lot of sun in the morning, in pots of about 40x15x25 cm and have holes on the bottom without a water retention underneath.